# Baroque mordent with leading "slur"?

Tags: piano, baroque-period, harpsichord, mordent

I'm currently studying Bach's Harpsichord Concerto BWV 1052 on the piano and arrived at the second movement. In there, I noticed a mordent that I'm not all too sure how to play. Here's a picture, it's the measure at the bottom left:
[image]

It looks like a slur that precedes the mordent. Am I right to assume this would mean having to play the E before playing the mordent as intended?

Comment: The marked 4323 fingering should be a big hint that the editor intends it to be played as A G F♯ G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]What ever this is - a slur or not - the E has to be played on the second eight of the bar and preceding the mordent, as in the right hand are first to be played A and G. In my opinion the editor wanted to propose the idea to attack the mordent GF#G with an approach from the upper note A

I have the Urtext Edition of Bärenreiter and here in this measure is only a proper  mordent.
(This concert is a transcription - of the lost violin  concerto - by Bachs son Carl Philip Emmanuel, but the harpsichord part has been controlled by J.S.Bach.

I‘ve right now realized that the transcription of C.P.E. Bach is in the appendix of thebook in there is no mordent at all.